# Deriving volume of parallelepiped as a function of edge lengths and angles between the edges

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

In [Wikipedia it is stated that the volume of the parallelepiped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) given its edge  lengths $a,b,c$, and the internal angles between the edges $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma $ is:

\begin{equation*}
V=abc\sqrt{1+2\cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma -\cos ^{2}\alpha
- \cos^{2}\beta - \cos ^{2}\gamma }\qquad(*).
\end{equation*}

I was not able to derive it by using the determinant formula and expressing $\cos \alpha ,\cos \beta ,\cos \gamma $ in terms of $a,b,c$ and $\alpha
,\beta ,\gamma $. For instance

\begin{equation*}
a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3}=ab\cos \alpha .
\end{equation*}

**Question:** Could you give a hint on how can the formula (*) be proved?

Comment: I amended the formula to agree with what wikipedia actually states.

Comment: @Robin: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The volume satisfies $V=|\det D|$ where $D$ is the matrix
$$\pmatrix{a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&b_2&c_3}$$
where $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is the vector corresponding to $a$ etc.
Thus
$$V^2=\det(DD^t)=\det
\pmatrix{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}
&\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}
&\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c}\\
\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{a}
&\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b}
&\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c}\\
\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{a}
&\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{b}
&\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{c}}.$$

Now you can express $V^2$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$ and the various
cosines.

Answer (score 4):

Please see this link, under trigonometric approach: http://www.ehow.com/how_6545076_prove-formula-volume-cuboids.html